# Share variables on server between Python and C#

Tags: python, c#, redis, memcached, key-value-store

I have a Jetson Nano on which I'm running a python script and a PC on which a C# program is running. I would like to create a list of shared variables that are continuously monitored by both the python and C# programs. If python script on Jetson Nano modifies a boolean variable from True to False, C# should be able to see the modified value instantly. I read about Redis and Memcached, but I'm not sure if that is fast enough.  Any suggestions?